# Remove list in item using duplicate item of other list

Tags: python

I'm working with dates in python.

```
d = []
t = []
for row in cursor: 
    emp = row[2]  #employee ID
    logtype = row[4]  # 'I' For login, 'O' for logout.
    log = row[3]   # time 

    day = log.strftime("%d")
    month = log.strftime("%m")
    year = log.strftime("%y")
    times = log.strftime("%I:%M")

    if (logtype == 'I') :
        d.append(day)
        t.append(times)
    

#the problem
time = list(set(t)) #len(22)
day = list(set(d))  #len(23)
```

## RESULT

```
Day = ['03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '09', '10', '11', '11', '12', '13', '14', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28']

Time = ['08:05', '08:01', '08:08', '10:33', '08:05', '06:53', '08:15', '08:03', '08:06', '08:11', '08:05', '08:03', '09:23', '08:10', '08:05', '08:10', '08:26', '01:43', '08:01', '08:10', '01:14', '08:06', '08:06']
```

I want to remove the repeating day(11) at the same time its value in time.

**UPDATE**

```
from collections import Counter        
#identify repeating day in dex number duplicate
dup = [i for key in (key for key, count in Counter(day).items() if count > 1) for i, x in enumerate(day) if x == key]
```

I managed to find the index of the duplicate using the above code then I remove the other except the last occurrence of the duplicate then appended by the code below

```
for x in dup[:-1]:
   time.pop(x)
   day.pop(x)
   day2.append(adlaw)
   time2.append(time)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you've tried. Does it work?

Comment: I am confused *"how to remove the list item in Time using duplicate value of Day."* but your `Day` is already having unique values, Right? Please also mention the structure of the list you desire and what you tried to achieve that

Comment: So you want to for example remove `08:06` because there are two `11`s in `Day`?

Comment: Yes sir. That's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) both lists, group by day, and take the first occurrence of the date in the group, dropping the following ones (duplicates), that is, if you want to keep the first item.

Do it in one-line using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
[list(e[1])[0][1] for e in itertools.groupby(zip(Day,Time),lambda t:t[0])])
```

result:

```
['08:05', '08:01', '08:08', '10:33', '08:05', '06:53', '08:15', '08:03', '08:11', '08:05', '08:03', '09:23', '08:10', '08:05', '08:10', '08:26', '01:43', '08:01', '08:10', '01:14', '08:06', '08:06']
```

if you wanted to keep the *last* item, just replace term by `list(e[1])[-1][1]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do what @Keiwan suggested, then consider creating a new list rather than removing unneeded values. Removing an element from a list runtime complexity is O(n), while appending an item to a list is usually of O(1).

The right solution, therefore, would be -

- having a set of "already used days", initialized to be empty
- having a list of new times, initialized to be empty
- running over the list of days
- for each day, check if it appears in the "already used"; if it is - skip it. If it is not - add it to that set, and append the appropriate time to "new times".